# In PHP when using fgets() to read from file how to exclude "brake row"

Tags: php, fgets

I'm writing simple function witch will read data from myfile.txt with fgets().
Content of file is something like:

```
1

2

3

4
```

Function to get first value (1):

```
$f = fopen ("myfile.txt", "r");
$mystring = fgets ($f);
```

Now, when I use `$mystring` to write in file like:

```
$f1 = fopen ("myfile2.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($f1, 'text' . $mystrin . 'more text');
```

text 'more text' goes to new row.

I want to have it in in same row with other text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When reading a file using [`fgets()`](http://php.net/fgets) it will include the newline at the end. You only need to remove it.

```
$mystring = trim ($mystring);
```

This will remove any leading and trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mystring = rtrim ($mystring, PHP_EOL);
```

Will remove any trailing newlines.